# How to st get parameter filters with slashes in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

For example `https://www.example.com/cat/cat1/cat2?brand=HP` to be `https://www.example.com/cat/cat1/cat2/HP`.
My `.htaccess` looks this way:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Categories are set properly, but the filters always show the native way with `?key=valye&key2=value2` etc.

Comment: Could you please confirm `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` which kind of URLs you are trying to handle here? Because you may end up with some other issues even for urls which should be accessible too

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to hit `https://www.example.com/cat/cat1/cat2/HP` then try following. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $1?brand=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Toma Tomov, could you please confirm `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` which kind of URLs you are trying to handle here? Because you may end up with some other issues even for urls which should be accessible too.